# Inserting data from an old database to a new one without deleting new data

Tags: mysql

I recently updated my database, causing it to erase all data. Unfortunately, I imported a 2 weeks old sql backup in my new database instead of the newest...

How can I import the missing data without destroying the new one (2 days have passed since the server update) ? The IDs have been taken by the new data so now my newest SQL backup that says `INSERT INTO table1 (ID, ID_Table2) VALUES (123, 456)` are no longer true since that reference to `Table2` will need the new ID !

Comment: If `table1.id` has `AUTOINCREMENT` you can replace ids by `NULL` and MySQL will automatically set a new value for the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can select all rows that are not present yet. There might be a more elegant solution, but this should do the trick;

```
INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table` (`column_1`, `column_2`, ...)
SELECT `column_1`, `column_2`, ... FROM `old_database`.`old_table` AS `ot`
    WHERE `ot`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `new_database`.`new_table`)
```

Basically what you're doing here is selecting all the rows from the old table which are not present in the new database (the `NOT IN` clause), and insert these rows.

Comment: Yeah it would work for the first table, but how do I get the new ID created and use it as reference for the 2nd table ? (We're talking about 30 thousands lines, I can't do it manually)

Comment: I'd have to see your table structure, but it looks like you need a `JOIN`

Comment: Nevermind I think I found a solution :D on my old database, I update my table's ID so that it takes it's own value + 10000, all of my foreign key then update in cascade ! So now the IDs are not the same in my old and new database and I can safely import them